# What happens when a Python program exits and a library is loaded using ctypes?

Tags: python, driver, ctypes

I have tried to find some information on this, but nothing so far. The scenario is a Python program that uses a C based library loaded with `ctypes` and then encounters an unhandled exception. Will Python unlioad the library? Or will it matter?

The main reason why this is an issue is that the library in question is a device driver, and I want to avoid leaving the hardware in the wrong state should something go wrong.

Comment: You may wrap your code in try block and perform required clean up in finally block.

Comment: Yes, that is one solution. But I was trying to find out if there was another way to deal with it. Things will obviously depend on the device driver itself, but for this question I'm mainly interested in knowing what goes on "behind the scenes" in the scenario I described.

Comment: When any program exits, the OS (Windows, Linux etc) clears all resources associated with it, including all shared libraries being loaded on startup or during program lifecycle. Python interpreter is a program, so when it exits after a Python program completes its execution or simply dies, the system clears all resources

Comment: However in your case the hardware, not the library may be left in an inconsistent state if its driver hadn't performed the correct shutdown before the termination. Whether or not it matters for your case depends on hardware and the library, but in this case I'd bet it would be better to setup an abnormal termination handler and perform required shutdown actions there.

Comment: Beware however that there could be fatal irrecoverable errors, for which you can't provide a viable safebelt solutions, so prepare yourself that you may need to provide an option to perform complete device reset upon _startup_

Comment: OK, so there is probably nothing more happening than the program (Python) detaching from the library.

I'm thinking of an option where the library could handle this, for example, in Windows to do a safe shutdown in DLL_PROCESS_DETACH in the DllHandler. However, the driver is given, but I could perhaps ask if something like that is implemented.

Comment: Device reset on startup is a good idea, should be included in any case. Thanks!

Comment: Software can only access hardware from kernel mode. The user-mode DLL probably provides a convenient, high-level API for the device driver -- as opposed to having to call [`DeviceIoControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216) to directly request device operations using control codes. The device driver receives an [`IRP_MJ_CLEANUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550718) I/O Request Packet (IRP) when the reference count on the associated file object drops to zero, such as when all handles in a process are closed at exit.